# Errors when using add = TRUE in hist function in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to create an overlapping relative frequency table with hist function.
I run the following code in r script and it works, but when I run it in markdown it gives me an error

```
with(newtable,hist(weight[Habit == 'NonSmoker'],prob = TRUE, density =  20, col = 'red',xlab = 'Weight(in ounces)', main = 'Histogram of weight by Smoking Status' , xlim = range(weight), ylim = c(0,0.03)))
with(newtable,hist(weight[Habit == 'Smoker'],prob = TRUE, density = 30, col = 'blue', breaks = 20, add = TRUE))
```

error

```
Error in segments(lx1, ly1, lx2, ly2, ...) : plot.new has not been called yet
```

can anybody tell my how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue.

The following minimal RMarkdown example doesn't produce any errors.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  html_document: default
---

```{r}
breaks <- seq(16, 34, by = 2)
with(mtcars, hist(mpg[cyl == 6], col = rgb(1,0,0,0.5), breaks = breaks))
with(mtcars, hist(mpg[cyl == 4], col = rgb(0,0,1,0.5), breaks = breaks, add = T))
```
````

Output

[image]